# Disable Visual Studio Quick Info pop up on mouse hover

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to disable this pop up window I believe is called "Quick Info" Visual Studio is displaying when hovering over collapsed code as seen in the image below?

I found this extension named [Tame Visual Studio Editor Tool Tips](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KarlShifflettkdawg.TameVisualStudioEditorToolTips) that sounded like it should take care of this problem but it didn't...

[image]